# Spring MVC setup

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, installation

I want to learn `SpringMVC` but it seems tutorials from the net doesn't show exactly how to setup eclipse for the said framework

I already download `spring-framework-4.0.0.M2` from the net and `commons-logging-1.1.3` but still i think i lack the other jars that i don't exactly know.

Do i need also to download `JSTL` jar? or how about `JSON`? and i don't see any tutorial that make a step by step setup on eclipse, i'm really taking a while now finding what things do i need and how to properly setup my eclipse for starting the SpringMVC tutorials.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at spring tools suite. It provides spring templates projects that is already configured to use. 
Download sts [here](http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts-ggts) and follow [tutorial](http://manueljordan.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/creating-a-spring-web-mvc-project-with-springsource-tool-suite/)

If you want to have better background with adding required libraries and project configuration management read this [book](http://www.sonatype.com/resources/books/maven-by-example).

Answer (score 0):

Don't download any jar.
Just use Maven. From Eclipse window go to Eclipse Market - and download maven plugin.
Then you have to download Tomcat. Set up Tomcat environment in eclipse.
Create new Dynamic Web project, right click on the project and in context menu - click Convert to Maven.

The *.POM file will appear in your project. Open it, if Maven plugin is installed, you will see a special Maven window. Click Dependencies pane, and try to add dependencies - type  org.springframework, you will see list of dependencies, choose one.

Open web.xml and change it to support spring mvc - dispather servlet.
Create spring context file (file with beans), and name it properly (see in books how to name it).

Try to run Tomcat from eclipse - if it fails - see log in eclipse - For sure Class-not-found exception there will be. Find out what class and in what dependency. Try to add that dependency into *.POM file. Try to run again.

Comment: Doesn't JSTL also included when i download the plug-in?